# WordPress and jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am fairly new to using jQuery in WordPress and I am trying to write jQuery scripts in a separate file.

What is the difference between the following two syntaxes of setting up the external file:

#### Version I

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#radio").buttonset();
});
```

#### Version II

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#radio").buttonset();
}
```

Comment: whats WordPress got to do with this question?

Comment: Agreed, @Bainternet - it ain't WP specific at all. However, if you encounter noConflict mode for the very first time with WP, I can see why it would seem as if it was.

Answer (score 6):

### jQuery.noConflict()

jQuery is included in WordPress in [noConflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), so as to work with other javascript extensions that also use `$` as an alias.

Hence your above Version II will not work with the WP native jQuery loading.

### What is jQuery?

jQuery is *not* a language. It is nothing but a (massive) javascript object. That object's name is `jQuery`. When `.noConflict()` is not applied, `$` is an alias for the `jQuery` object.

### Best practice for external files

Wrap the entire js in a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work), pass it the `jQuery` object and `$` as an argument. Inside you can write your script the way you're used to:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#radio").buttonset();
    }
})(jQuery);
```