# jQuery vs. $ - Creating jQuery scripts in JavaScript in WordPress using External Libraries

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to utilize Trent Richardson's Date Time Picker ([see here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)).

I am trying to get the selected time when the popup closes, so I am using the following code (in an external .js file):

```
jQuery(function()
{
    var startDateTextBox = jQuery('#start_date_field');

    startDateTextBox.datetimepicker(
    {
        onClose: function(dateText, inst)
        {
            var testStartDate = startDateTextBox.datetimepicker('getDate');
            alert(testStartDate);
        }
    });
});
```

However, the alert is coming up saying that the variable is undefined (which also happens when I step through the function).  What am I doing wrong?

I opened up Trent's source and I noticed that he is using $ in place of jQuery - I saw elsewhere that you should always use jQuery in WordPress in order to put it into 'no conflict mode' - is that accurate?  What are the ramifications of using $ instead of jQuery?

Comment: As for your confusion on what `.noConflict()` does and is: Have you searched this site (or [SO] or elsewhere) for the topic? See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91594/wordpress-and-jquery/91598#91598), for instance.

Comment: I just tried what do described and it worked for me. Have you checked your source code? Where and how do you enqueue/include the files? The Timepicker itself is working, but it's not giving you the date on close? Can we see the live site?