# wp_localize_script not create variable in head section

Tags: ajax, wp-enqueue-script, variables, wp-localize-script

I try to make an ajax function in wordpress and I enqueued my script and declared my variables like this in `functions.php`:

```
function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'load_post', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/load_post.js', 
        array( 'jquery' ), 
        '1.0', 
        1
    );
    wp_localize_script( 
        'load_post', 
        'wp_ajax',
        array( 
            'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'ajax_nonce' )
        )
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts');
```

load_post.js :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 

    jQuery('#next-container').click(function($) {

        var $container = jQuery('#isotope-container');
        var IDs = [];
        jQuery(".element").each(function($){ IDs.push(this.id); });

        jQuery('#next-container').html('loading');

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: wp_ajax.url,
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {  action: 'load_post',  
                     ajax_nonce: wp_ajax.nonce,
                     post_ids: IDs,  
                  },  //{'post_ids[]': IDs },
            success: function(data) {
                    jQuery('#next-container').html(''); 
                    $container.isotope( 'insert', $(data)); 
                    }
        })
    })
})
```

However in my `load_post.js` I can't get `wp_ajax` variable. I don't see any variable added in the head section of my source code in google chrome or IE.

Where comes from my problem? Do I miss something?

Comment: Please add your javascript code to the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct.
`alert(wp_ajax.nonce);` should display the nonce.
You can also verify the existence of the `wp_ajax` object via `console.log(wp_ajax)` in your browser's Javascript console.

[`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) adds the object(s) to the footer (a call to `wp_footer()` should be present in the theme's *footer.php* file).
It'll look like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var wp_ajax = {"url":"http://example.com","nonce":"123XYZ"};
    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It's because I forget to add `wp_footer()` ! I was thinking it was in `wp_head()`! Now I see the variable in the footer in the source code! But I have a problem with my javascript... here `$container.isotope( 'insert', $(data))` : `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function `

Comment: 1. As a general note: That's a javascript error unrelated to WordPress and would hence be on-topic on [SO]. | 2. `$(data)` is likely supposed to be a variable. Currently your passing `data` to the jQuery object (`$`). You likely want `$data`. Which, as an aside, goes to show why prefixing JS variables with a dollar sign is not a good practice, IMHO. | 3. http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/adding-items.html#insert_method

Comment: This script works great in my html template but know with wordpress it don't works...

Comment: With or without $ prefix I've got problem. I don't have any problem with this without wordpress. It seems to comes from wordpress and the way that jquery prefix is used...

Comment: Fair enuff, that's likely a correct guess. `$` is not a "prefix" for jQuery, it's an alias. The name of the jQuery object is `jQuery` - use that instead, you'll be good. For more info: Refer to [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91594/wordpress-and-jquery/91598#91598).

Comment: ok but it's an isotope problem with wordpress. Insert method of isotope have a filter problem with wordpress. By changing the way to insert new elements it works with this : `$container.append($data).isotope('reloadItems').isotope({ sortBy: 'original-order' });` Putting `$data` or `data` give the same working result with this method. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Interesting. I have used isotope with WP extensively, never with conflicts - admittedly though, I have never needed the `insert` method. Good to know that manually chaining `append` and `reLayout` will do.