# This jQuery snippet doesn't seem to work with Wordpress

Tags: jquery

I'm not really that much of a jQuery aficionado so I'm not really sure why this little jQuery modal lightbox snippet isn't working.

Am I missing any kind of WP specific code?

I'm enqueueing the script in the header if that helps

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var lightBox = $('#lightbox'),
    lightBoxContent = $('#lb-content');
    var positionLightbox = function() {
        var veiwWidth = $(window).width(),
        lbContentMargin = (veiwWidth / 2) - 148,
        lbContent = $('#lb-content');
        lbContent.css({
            'left' : lbContentMargin,
            'top' : $(window).scrollTop() + 50 + 'px'
        });
    };

    $('.modal-trigger').click(function() {
        lightBox.fadeIn(function() {
        lightBoxContent.show();
    });
    positionLightbox();
    });
    $('#lb-close').click(function() {
        lightBox.hide();
        lightBoxContent.hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you getting some errors in firebug|console|etc. ?

Comment: @iEmanuele I do, I get this error `TypeError: $ is not a function
$(window).load(function(){`

Comment: ok, follow the Otto's answer : )

Comment: In the future, please try searching for related issues before posting new questions. This one has been asked and [answered](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91594/wordpress-and-jquery/91598#91598), [several times](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=jquery%20%22noconflict%22).

Comment: As a rule of thumb when working with jQuery, always wrap your code in `(function($) { [...] })(jQuery)` to stop its use of the `$` conflicting with other libraries that do the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the problem was in your variable define syntax and also you need to wrap your jQuery script into [no conflict](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) wrapper, try this

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {
   // your function
});
```

or

```
(function($) {
  // your function
})(jQuery);
```

complete working script

```
(function($) {
   $(window).load(function() {
     var lightBox = $('#lightbox');
     var lightBoxContent = $('#lb-content');
     var positionLightbox = function() {
         var veiwWidth = $(window).width();
         var lbContentMargin = (veiwWidth / 2) - 148;
         var lbContent = $('#lb-content');
         lbContent.css({
           'left' : lbContentMargin,
           'top' : $(window).scrollTop() + 50 + 'px'
         });
     };

     $('.modal-trigger').click(function() {
         lightBox.fadeIn(function() {
         lightBoxContent.show();
     });
     positionLightbox();
     });
     $('#lb-close').click(function() {
         lightBox.hide();
         lightBoxContent.hide();
     });
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: That throws up this error `SyntaxError: missing : after property id - 
var lightBox = { $('#lightbox'),
modal....r=3.5.2 (line 2, col 20) 
`

Comment: oh something went wrong, edited try now

Comment: I get this error now `TypeError: $ is not a function $(window).load(function(){`

Comment: edited and wrapped into no conflict hope now it will be work

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained what the user was doing wrong, and why this solves the problem.

Comment: Please provide descriptive answers, rather than just code. WPSE is a **question and answer** site, not a code repository. :)

Comment: @t31os edited the answer as per your suggestions

Comment: @Anjum, after edit +1 from me.

Answer (score 7):

Most likely, it's because you're using the dollar sign shortcut without putting it inside a no-conflict wrapper.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

Comment: So would I just need to change `$(window).load(function(){` to `jQuery(window).load(function(){` ?

Comment: This should have been marked as the correct answer.

Comment: @Poisontonomes I don't know if there are some other errors in your jQuery. But even if so, the only wordpress-related error, and so the only reason for your question stay in this site, is the one pointed out by Otto. This is why I +1 this answer.

Comment: That should be: `jQuery(window).load(function($){}` (note the passing of the `$`).