# jQuery on Underscores menu

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to add a class to an element within the main menu, but nothing is happening. I'm using Underscores starter theme, which has this in the header.php:

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
        'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
        'after'          => '<span class="fa fa-times"></span>',
    ) );
?>
```

I then put this in the navigation.js file (also tried inline in the footer.php):

```
$(".menu-item-has-children .span").click(function() {
    $(".menu-item-has-children .sub-menu").removeClass("toggled");
    $(this).next(".sub-menu").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

But nothing happens. I've also tried a simple:

```
$('body').click(function() {
    alert("Yeah!");
});
```

And nothing happens there either. This *does* work:

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert("Yeah!");
}
```

jQuery is loading:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
```

navigation.js is enqueued in functions.php:

```
function themename_scripts() {

wp_enqueue_style( 'themename-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

wp_enqueue_script( 'themename-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '20151215', true );

wp_enqueue_script( 'themename-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '20151215', true );

if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themename_scripts' );
```

...So what basic error have I made?

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you inspect the page (E.g $ is not a function)? Are you using/have you tried wrapping your jQuery code in a document ready function? Where is navigation.js being enqueued?

Comment: Ah yes, I get $ is not a function. Wrapping in document ready function doesn't seem to help. navigation.js Is being enqueued in functions.php - I have edited my question to detail this.

Comment: WordPress loads jQuery in noConflict. You can switch all your `$` with `jQuery` or read [this answer for more information](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91598/7355)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't passed jquery as a dependency for your script, and you are using the dollar sign too, which is not directly supported in WordPress due to conflict.

First, pass jQuery as a requirement while enqueuing your `navigation.js`:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
    'themename-navigation', 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', 
    array('jquery'), 
    '20151215', 
    true 
);
```

Then, wrap your code in a self invoking function:

```
(function($){
    // You have access to $ here
})(jQuery);
```

Or even better,  define the `$`:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

$('body').click(function() {
    alert("Yeah!");
});
```

Done.

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I've added jQuery to the header cause I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't work without it when it was supposed to be included already. Enqueing with navigation ... brilliant!